# How to use jsonata to return multiple objects, distributing the first key/value, which will always be dateTime, with the remaining keys varying

Tags: jsonata

How can jsonata be used to transform:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "dateTime": "2019-10-19T12:53:54.043Z",
      "Reactor3.Level": 1.51860072870498,
      "Reactor3.Temp": 27.1360543141452
    },
    {
      "dateTime": "2019-10-19T12:55:54.043Z",
      "Reactor3.Press": 88.9,
      "Reactor3.Temp": 24.1418981047159
    }
  ]
}
```

Into a series of objects containing only two keys of {"dateTime":"2019-10-19T12:53:54.043Z", key[1]:value[1]},{"dateTime":"2019-10-19T12:53:54.043Z",key[2]:value[2]}
Such as the following:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "dateTime": "2019-10-19T12:53:54.043Z",
      "Reactor3.Level": 1.51860072870498
    },
    {
      "dateTime": "2019-10-19T12:53:54.043Z",
      "Reactor3.Temp": 27.1360543141452
    },
    {
      "dateTime": "2019-10-19T12:55:54.043Z",
      "Reactor3.Press": 88.9
    },
    {
      "dateTime": "2019-10-19T12:55:54.043Z",
      "Reactor3.Temp": 24.1418981047159
    }
  ]
}
```

Where the first key will always be dateTime, the other keys will vary, and I'd like to break out all other keys/values by dateTime?
Here Reactor3.Level, Reactor3.Temp, Reactor3.Press are just examples that will change.

EDIT: In the following I am adding a more generic version of my problem.
I am essentially looking for a JSONata query to transform this input:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "TS": "TS1",
      "V1": 1,
      "V2": 2
    },
    {
      "TS": "TS2",
      "V2": 9,
      "V3": 8,
      "V4": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

where key "TS" is the first key in every set,
and the other keys will vary.
And transform it into this output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "TS": "TS1",
      "V1": 1
    },
    {
      "TS": "TS1",
      "V2": 2
    },
    {
      "TS": "TS2",
      "V2": 9
    },
    {
      "TS": "TS2",
      "V3": 8
    },
    {
      "TS": "TS2",
      "V4": 7
    }
  ]
}
```

[SOLVED] SteveR solved my problem below, I just want to add a Node-RED "payload" friendly version of the solution here:
Link: http://try.jsonata.org/HJCjoHxoS

payload modified JSONata:

```
payload.$ ~> | $ | { "data": data.(
    $obj := $;
    $key := "dateTime";
    $keys($obj)[$ != $key].{
        $key : $lookup($obj, $key),
        $: $lookup($obj, $)
    }
) } |
```

Thanks again to @SteveR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting challenge, Jeff -- but if object properties do not have a guaranteed order, it may not be possible to do reliably... is it **always** the "first" property that needs to be distributed over the rest of them, or can you say for sure that it will always be called `TS` (using your simplified example)?

That being said, I *did* find an expression that seems to work, albeit only within my limited testing:

```
data.(
    $obj := $;
    $keys($obj)[[1..100]].(
        $key := $keys($obj)[0];
        {
            $key : $lookup($obj, $key),
            $: $lookup($obj, $)
        }
    )
)
```

Essentially, for each of the incoming objects, get its keys -- for each key with index between 1 - 100 (I know, it's an artificial limit), create the new object `{ key[0]: val[0], key[i]: val[i] }`

You can try to tweak it here if you would like => http://try.jsonata.org/ryh3hqM5H

If you *can* say for sure that the first property is called "TS", I would use that named property to simplify the expression, like this:

```
data.(
    $obj := $;
    $key := "TS";
    $keys($obj)[$ != $key].{
        $key : $lookup($obj, $key),
        $: $lookup($obj, $)
    }
)
```

I'm sure there are better ways to accomplish the same transformation, but I hope this helps...

Good luck!

**EDIT**: I see that I lost the outer object with its `data` property. You can just wrap it around the expression(s) I listed, or if there are other properties that need to be maintained, use the object transform syntax to only modify that one `data` property:

```
$$ ~> | $ | { "data": data.(
    $obj := $;
    $key := "dateTime";
    $keys($obj)[$ != $key].{
        $key : $lookup($obj, $key),
        $: $lookup($obj, $)
    }
) } |
```

Comment: Wow, that works great and I would have NEVER figured that out. I'm still wrapping my head around how this works.

Comment: I agree, it's rather hard to read! In this case, I would say it's probably better to use a plain JS function to do the iterations and build the new objects -- especially for the person who has to maintain this logic in the future...

Comment: Here is a node-RED "payload" friendly version: